# Does django adminplus effects performance?

Tags: python, django, apache

I have used django-adminplus to register custom views with django-filters in the admin site. This is slowing down the performance of my django project. I am using Apache as my http webserver as also my static file renderer as I 'HAVE' to do it so. I cannot use gninx nor gunicorn. The views render several 100k records. I have about 30-40 custom views registered with search/ filter option on the admin site. How do I improve the performance. I use linux debian, 64 GB RAM. django 1.6.5 . Thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem for slow response was with the custom views which did not have pagination. After implementing this feature, response became fast :)